# How to select month from sql date in column where month is currentmonth

Tags: php, html, sql, json

I need to make a select statement that returns Voornaam, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam from customer WHERE (I have a column in my database which is called Geboortedatum, in here I have a date. I need al the values named above where Geboortedatum is the same as `$currentmonth`. I already have a json function which returns the `currentmonth`.) I am stuck with what to put after WHERE.
Just to be clear: I need Voornaam, Tussenvoegsel and Achternaam where the month of Geboortedatum(DD-MM-YYYY) from my table customer is the same as `$currentmonth`.

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "Habt2002", "fca");

if ($_POST['key'] == 'bijnaJarig') {
    $currentmonth = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['currentmonth']);
    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT Voornaam, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam, Telefoonnummer, Email 
                        FROM customer 
                        WHERE ??????? ");
    $data = $sql->fetch_array();
    $jsonArray = array(
        'voornaam' => $data['Voornaam'],
        'tussenvoegsel' => $data['Tussenvoegsel'],
        'achternaam' => $data['Achternaam'],
        'telefoonnummer' => $data['Telefoonnummer'],
        'emailbijnajarig' => $data['Email']
    );

    exit(json_encode($jsonArray));
}
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MySQL?

Comment: Current Year as well? You don't want to get customer's from June 2018 in the result set, or do you?

Comment: Is `Geboortedatum` defined as a DATETIME or DATE column or is it some kind of string like VARCHAR, because `DD-MM-YYYY` is not a standard DATE format

Comment: I am using MySQL. This is my database https://imgur.com/a/PNhngUm

Comment: Geboortedatum is defined as date, sorry I am probably wrong about the format @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1):

Using the `MONTH()` and `CURDATE()` MySQL functions you can do

```
WHERE MONTH(Geboortedatum) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

You may also want to add a `YEAR()` check

```
AND YEAR(Geboortedatum) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

unless you want all data for this month over multiple years

#### Second Issue

You are only fetching ONE row from the resultset, you either need to loop over the `n` rows in the resultset OR use the `fetch_all()` method. In this case the `fetch_all()` seems like the simplest approach.

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "xxxx", "fca");
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

if ($_POST['key'] == 'bijnaJarig') {
    
    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT Voornaam, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam, Telefoonnummer, Email 
                        FROM customer 
                        WHERE MONTH(Geboortedatum) = MONTH(CURDATE())");
    $all_rows= $sql->fetch_all();

    echo json_encode($all_rows);
}
```

Comment: Darn, beat me by a handful of keystrokes :)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. (I need all  the data for this month over multiple years because I need to make a list of users who almost have their birthday)

Comment: Problem I am having now is that this only returns 1 user. Any solutions?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/nIZB2UI ) This are my records, this is what it returns [link](https://imgur.com/a/zjSfj0n)