# Put all MYSQL results in variable to use in Ajax

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

I have made a select statement that selects Voornaam, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam, Email and Telefoonnummer from the customers who almost have their birthday. This statement outputs multiple results. I would like to use each result in ajax later to put them in my modal. How do I do this?

This is for a MySQL database

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "Habt2002", "fca");

if ($_POST['key'] == 'bijnaJarig') {
    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT id, Voornaam, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam, Telefoonnummer, Email 
                        FROM customer 
                        WHERE MONTH(Geboortedatum) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ");
}
```

I also tried to use a variation on the code below to output it. The problem with that is that it only outputs 1 result.

```
if ($_POST['key'] == 'getRowData') {
    $rowID = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['rowID']);
    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT Voornaam, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam, 
                                Telefoonnummer, Email, Geboortedatum, 
                                Plaats, Postadres, Huisnummer, Postcode, 
                                Leeftijdsgroep, Extratraining, 
                                Verhogingcontributies, Contributies, 
                                Betaald 
                        FROM customer 
                        WHERE id ='$rowID'");
    $data = $sql->fetch_array();
    $jsonArray = array(
            'voornaam' => $data['Voornaam'],
            'tussenvoegsel' => $data['Tussenvoegsel'],
            'achternaam' => $data['Achternaam'],
            'telefoonnummer' => $data['Telefoonnummer'],
            'email' => $data['Email'],
            'geboortedatum' => $data['Geboortedatum'],
            'plaats' => $data['Plaats'],
            'postadres' => $data['Postadres'],
            'huisnummer' => $data['Huisnummer'],
            'postcode' => $data['Postcode'],
            'leeftijdsgroep' => $data['Leeftijdsgroep'],
            'extratraining' => $data['Extratraining'],
            'verhogingcontributies' => $data['Verhogingcontributies'],
            'contributies' => $data['Contributies'],
            'betaald' => $data['Betaald']
        );

        exit(json_encode($jsonArray));
    }
```

This is the Ajax code I have for now

```
function bijnaJarig() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                key: 'bijnaJarig',
            }, success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                $("#bijnaJarigTable").modal('show');
            }

    })
}
```

I know how to put the variables in a modal but I want to know how do I get these variables (more than 1 result)

Comment: Like I said [in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56795357/2310830) You are ONLY FETCHING ONE ROW FROM Potentially multiple rows in the resultset

Comment: I also changed `exit(json_encode($jsonArray));` to `echo json_encode($jsonArray);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding logging statements to find out why you are only seeing one row of results? If you are certain that your query is returning multiple rows, then check what `$data` contains.

[Take a look at the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-array-returnvalues): `$data` will only contain one of the rows. You need to continue to call `fetch_array()` [to read the next rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#95881).

```php
// Read rows until result is empty
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

// Read columns from each row
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['Column_Name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, you are only reading ONE row from a resultset that might contain many rows, so you would have to write a loop OR just `fetch_all()`. The `fetch_all()` is simpler here as all the rows you get back from the database will look exactly like the intermediate array you were trying to create.

```
if ($_POST['key'] == 'getRowData') {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT Voornaam, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam, 
                Telefoonnummer, Email, Geboortedatum, 
                Plaats, Postadres, Huisnummer, Postcode, 
                Leeftijdsgroep, Extratraining, 
                Verhogingcontributies, Contributies, 
                Betaald 
        FROM customer 
        WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['rowID'] );
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // fetch ALL the results
    $jsonArray = $result->fetch_all();

    echo json_encode($jsonArray);
}
```

If you do it as a loop it would be like this

```
if ($_POST['key'] == 'getRowData') {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT Voornaam, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam, 
                Telefoonnummer, Email, Geboortedatum, 
                Plaats, Postadres, Huisnummer, Postcode, 
                Leeftijdsgroep, Extratraining, 
                Verhogingcontributies, Contributies, 
                Betaald 
        FROM customer 
        WHERE id = ?"
    );
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['rowID']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // fetch ALL the results
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $jsonArray[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($jsonArray);
}
```

Comment: Yea thansk for that.

Comment: @Dharman Cant cook Dinner and edit SQL Injection errors out of other peoples code. But I get there eventually

Comment: I replaced the variable in query with placeholder.

Comment: I obviously need to go and eat :)